# Catching certificate domain name mismatch openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate

How do I catch the domain name mismatch?

I use `SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl)` to get the certificate, then `SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);` to verify the certificate. How can i catch the domain name mismatch here as I am not catching it currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SSL_get_verify_result` doesnot do a hostname mismatch search. We have to do that manually taking into consideration multiple CN's and subject alternative names(SAN's) that come in the certificate.

The functions that can be used for handling multiple CN's are :

```
int lastpos = -1;
lastpos=X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(X509_get_subject_name(cert), NID_commonName, lastpos);
X509_NAME_get_entry(X509_get_subject_name(cert), lastpos);
```

calling `X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID` again using the new lastpos will give us the next CN until it returns -1 which says there are no more CN's available.

this function gives a `X509_NAME_ENTRY *`, which can be converted to `char *` using `ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8`.

Be sure to consider the wildcards that come in the SAN's and CN's